# How to control access of custom entities from contrib modules?

Tags: entities

What is the better way to control the access of custom entities from contrib modules in Drupal?

I thought 2 diferents ways: **hook_menu_alter** *access callback* and **entity_info_alter** *access callback*.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are trying to do? Are you writing a module that is creating custom entities? Are you trying to control user access?

Comment: I can either control access of any entity overriding both hook_menu_alter or hook_entity_info_alter. Which is the advantages and disadvantages of each one?

For example, im using eck to construct my entities.